# Can I identify the interrupt source if I only have the interrupt vector under Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Let me explain more detail about my question:
I have a Linux system, and it receive a lot of interrupts with the same interrupt vector number, such as 224, and it has affect the system's performance a lot. I want to identify which part of the system (probably one of the I/O devices) had issued so many interrupts.
So, can I identify the source of the interrupt with the vector number under Linux system? If yes, then how to do it? If not, why and what kinds of information do I need? If there is a mapping table, or something like that, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can find the interrupt vector, counter and name of interrupt by doing:

```
cat /proc/interrupts
```

If the interrupt is shared between several devices you could if possible try to deactivate one of the devices and see how that affects the increase of the interrupt count. If the fast increase then stops you have found the source that is loading your system.

Comment: Ria, how can I deactivate one device? Just unload its driver?

Comment: That could be one thing to do if the driver is dynamically linked. Also you could remove MMC/SD cards, stop ethernet, stop WLAN, remove USB dongles etc.